# Jsoup select element from CSS

Tags: android, jquery, html, css, jsoup

How can I get all images without first class: content.slide0.

In my example I use Jsoup library, which show selectable elements in WebView.

**Elements element = doc.select("HERE_SOLUTION");**

```
  <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">
        <title>TESTING TITLE</title>
        <meta name="description" content="">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1">

        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/normalize.min.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.css?4231">

        <script src="js/vendor/modernizr-2.6.2.min.js"></script>

        <style type="text/css" media="screen">
        body {
            background: #fe9600 url('images/1389219790_bg2.jpg') no-repeat fixed top center;
        }

        #content.slide0 {
            background: url('img/1234.jpg') no-repeat scroll top left;
            width: 970px;
            height: 474px;
            margin: 0 auto;
        }

        #content.slide1 {
            background: url('images/1235.jpg') no-repeat scroll top left;
            width: 970px;
            height: 474px;
            margin: 0 auto;
        }

        #content.slide2 {
            background: url('images/1236.jpg') no-repeat scroll top left;
            width: 970px;
            height: 474px;
            margin: 0 auto;
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Jsoup parses HTML but not CSS. Since you are attempting to get images from CSS, you cannot use Jsoup selectors. You should probably use regular expressions.
In you `'.*'` regex should extract
1. 'img/1234.jpg'
2. 'images/1235.jpg'
3. 'images/1236.jpg'
4. 'images/1389219790_bg2.jpg'

Last one may be unwanted. You can remove this probably checking length of string or so.

Alternatively you can use CSS parser like [this](http://cssparser.sourceforge.net/).

Hope this helps!